# How to make mercurial run script on push?

Tags: mercurial

I have a server which hosts a mercurial repository with hgwebdir. Is it possible to make mercurial to run a script when someone pushes to this repository?
Currently I use a script that checks the repository state every few minutes, but this is obviously an ugly solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add a hook to your Mercurial server:

- Edit .hg/hgrc (or mercurial.ini on Windows)
- Add or edit the [hooks] section
- Associate a shell command to the hook you are interested in (in your case, the changegroup hook)

Look at [Handling repository events with hooks](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:ref) in the Mercurial red-bean book for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at mercurial hooks,

http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html